# Does JCache support EJB Transaction on cache read/write?

Tags: java, redis, transactions, redisson

Does `JCache` support `EJB Transaction` while cache read/write?

I want to clear cache entries that added during a transactional method call, if its transaction is rolled back.

I am using `Redis` as cache provider and `Redisson`'s `JCache` implementation as client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Support for JTA (Java Transaction API supported by EJBs), was initially planed in the JCache spec but [was removed](https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/issues/236) before the release of version 1.0

As for the last version of the spec, 1.1.1 ([available here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ijduF_tmHvBaUS7VBBU2ZN8_eEBiFaXXg9OI0_ZxCrA/edit?usp=sharing)) this hasn't changed.

Redisson on the other hand does provide a `XAResource` that can be enlisted in JTA transactions, using an specific API, as JCache doesn't provide it.

You can read more about it in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-manage-transactions-in-redis-on-java)